# How to compute mean/max of HuggingFace Transformers BERT token embeddings with attention mask?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the HuggingFace Transformers BERT model, and I want to compute a summary vector (a.k.a. embedding) over the tokens in a sentence, using either the `mean` or `max` function. The complication is that some tokens are `[PAD]`, so I want to ignore the vectors for those tokens when computing the average or max.

Here's an example. I initially instantiate a `BertTokenizer` and a `BertModel`:

```py
import torch
import transformers
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

transformer_name = 'bert-base-uncased'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(transformer_name, use_fast=True)

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(transformer_name)
```

I then input some sentences into the tokenizer and get out `input_ids` and `attention_mask`. Notably, an `attention_mask` value of 0 means that the token was a `[PAD]` that I can ignore.

```py
sentences = ['Deep learning is difficult yet very rewarding.',
             'Deep learning is not easy.',
             'But is rewarding if done right.']
tokenizer_result = tokenizer(sentences, max_length=32, padding=True, return_attention_mask=True, return_tensors='pt')

input_ids = tokenizer_result.input_ids
attention_mask = tokenizer_result.attention_mask

print(input_ids.shape) # torch.Size([3, 11])

print(input_ids)
# tensor([[  101,  2784,  4083,  2003,  3697,  2664,  2200, 10377,  2075,  1012,  102],
#         [  101,  2784,  4083,  2003,  2025,  3733,  1012,   102,     0,     0,    0],
#         [  101,  2021,  2003, 10377,  2075,  2065,  2589,  2157,  1012,   102,   0]])

print(attention_mask.shape) # torch.Size([3, 11])

print(attention_mask)
# tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Now, I call the BERT model to get the 768-D token embeddings (the top-layer hidden states).

```py
model_result = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, return_dict=True)

token_embeddings = model_result.last_hidden_state
print(token_embeddings.shape) # torch.Size([3, 11, 768])
```

So at this point, I have:

1. token embeddings in a [3, 11, 768] matrix: 3 sentences, 11 tokens, 768-D vector for each token.
2. attention mask in a [3, 11] matrix: 3 sentences, 11 tokens. A 1 value indicates non-`[PAD]`.

How do I compute the `mean` / `max` over the vectors for the valid, non-`[PAD]` tokens?

I tried using the attention mask as a mask and then called `torch.max()`, but I don't get the right dimensions:

```py
masked_token_embeddings = token_embeddings[attention_mask==1]
print(masked_token_embeddings.shape) # torch.Size([29, 768] <-- WRONG. SHOULD BE [3, 11, 768]

pooled = torch.max(masked_token_embeddings, 1)
print(pooled.values.shape) # torch.Size([29]) <-- WRONG. SHOULD BE [3, 768]
```

What I really want is a tensor of shape [3, 768]. That is, a 768-D vector for each of the 3 sentences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `max`, you can multiply with `attention_mask`:

```
pooled = torch.max((token_embeddings * attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1)), axis=1)
```

For `mean`, you can sum along the axis and divide by `attention_mask` along that axis:

```
mean_pooled = token_embeddings.sum(axis=1) / attention_mask.sum(axis=-1).unsqueeze(-1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't `mean_pooled` be implemented analogously to the max pooling, except you'd use `torch.mean`? Like this: `mean_pooled = torch.mean((token_embeddings * attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1)), axis=1)` ?

Comment: Using `token_embeddings * attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1)` is pretty slick. I didn't think of that.

Comment: This seems incorrect - PAD tokens are not embedded as 0-vectors; they represent context and position and thus have real valued elements. Therefore a sum over the token-wise axis will be computed with the PAD vectors, which probably isn't what we want. One work around I just came up with was setting the embeddings to 0 if the attention mask was 0, then summing, then dividing by # of tokens. In code, `state[inputs["attention_mask"] == 0] = 0`. This feels inefficient though, so I'm on the lookout for more elegant solutions

Comment: @AlexL: You wrote `This seems incorrect`. What `This` are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Quang, you can have a look at [sentence_transformers Pooling layer](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/models/Pooling.py).

For max pooling, they do this:

```py
input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
token_embeddings[input_mask_expanded == 0] = -1e9  # Set padding tokens to large negative value
pooled = torch.max(token_embeddings, 1)[0]
```

And for mean pooling they do the following:

```py
input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
sum_embeddings = torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1)
sum_mask = input_mask_expanded.sum(1)
sum_mask = torch.clamp(sum_mask, min=1e-9)
pooled = sum_embeddings / sum_mask
```

The max pooling presented in the accepted answer will suffer when the max is negative, and the implementation from sentence transformers changes token_embeddings, which throw an error when you want to use the embedding for back propagation:
`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation:`

If you're interested on anything back-prop related, you can do something like this:

```py
input_mask_expanded = torch.where(attention_mask==0, -1e-9, 0.).unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
pooled = torch.max(token_embeddings-input_mask_expanded, 1)[0] # Set padding tokens to large negative value
```

It's the same idea of making all masked tokens to be very small, but it doesn't change the token_embeddings while at it.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right.
[Look on hidden states for strings that go into tokenizer. For different strings, padding will have different embeddings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oivCS.png)

So, in order to properly pool embeddings, you need to ignore those padding vectors.

Let's say you want to get embeddings out of the last 4 layers of BERT (as it yields the best classification results):

```
#iterate over the last 4 layers and get embeddings for 
#strings without having embeddings from PAD tokens
m = []   
for i in range(len(hidden_states[0])):
   m.append([hidden_states[j+9][i,:,:][tokens["attention_mask"][i] !=0] for j in range(4)]) 

#average over all tokens embeddings
means = []
for i in range(len(hidden_states[0])):
    means.append(torch.stack(m[i]).mean(dim=1))

#stack embeddings for all strings
pooled = torch.stack(means).reshape(-1,1,3072)
```