# Why do I get different embeddings when I perform batch encoding in huggingface MT5 model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to encode some text using HuggingFace's mt5-base model. I am using the model as shown below

```py
from transformers import MT5EncoderModel, AutoTokenizer

model = MT5EncoderModel.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")

def get_t5_embeddings(texts):
    last_hidden_state = model(input_ids=tokenizer(texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).input_ids).last_hidden_state
    pooled_sentence = torch.max(last_hidden_state, dim=1)
    return pooled_sentence[0].detach().numpy()
```

I was doing some experiments when I noticed that the same text had a low cosine similarity score with itself. I did some digging and realized that the model was returning very different embeddings if I did the encoding in batches. To validate this, I ran a small experiment that generated embeddings for `Hello` and a list of 10 `Hello`s incrementally. and checking the embeddings of the `Hello` and the first `Hello` in the list (both of which should be same).

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i, (get_t5_embeddings(["Hello"])[0] == get_t5_embeddings(["Hello"]*i)[0]).sum())
```

This will return the number of values in the embeddings that match each other.
This was the result:

```
1 768
2 768
3 768
4 768
5 768
6 768
7 768
8 27
9 27
```

Every time I run it, I get mismatches if the batch size is more than 768.

Why am I getting different embeddings and how do I fix this?

Comment: The main "error" is from `pooled_sentence = torch.max(last_hidden_state, dim=1)`. Step back think a little what the `torch.max` is doing and what are you "pooling".

Answer (score 1):

### In Short

The main "error" is from `pooled_sentence = torch.max(last_hidden_state, dim=1)`. Step back think a little what the `torch.max` is doing and what are you "pooling".

---

### In Long

Depending on your longest sentence in the batch your token length will be different, so when you do a `torch.max`, since the max token is different, you'll get different sizes.

```
texts = ["hello world", "foo bar", "this is a foo bar sentence"]
last_hidden_state = model(input_ids=tokenizer(texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).input_ids).last_hidden_state

second_sentence_embeddings_1 = last_hidden_state[1]


texts = ["hello world", "foo bar"]
last_hidden_state = model(input_ids=tokenizer(texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).input_ids).last_hidden_state

second_sentence_embeddings_2 = last_hidden_state[1]

second_sentence_embeddings_1.shape, second_sentence_embeddings_2.shape
```

[out]:

```
(torch.Size([10, 768]), torch.Size([4, 768]))
```

#### First, solve the differing batch size outputs by using `pipeline`

```
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline(task="feature-extraction", model="google/mt5-base", framework="pt")

# See https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/20404
pipe.model = pipe.model.encoder 

hello_world = pipe(["hello world", "foo bar"], return_pt=True)

batch_mode = pipe(["hello world", "foo bar", "this is a foo bar sentence"], return_pt=True)


assert hello_world[1] == batch_mode[1]
```

#### But how do I get a vector of 768 dimensions per sentence?

TL;DR:

```
from transformers import MT5EncoderModel, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import FeatureExtractionPipeline


class LuigiThePlumber(FeatureExtractionPipeline):
    def postprocess(self, model_outputs):
        # If you just want it to return a torch.return_types.max, 
        # instead of plain tensor use 
        # `return torch.max(model_outputs.last_hidden_state, dim=1)`
        return torch.max(model_outputs.last_hidden_state, dim=1).values

model = MT5EncoderModel.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")

pipe = LuigiThePlumber(task="feature-extraction", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, framework="pt")

# See https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/20404
pipe.model = pipe.model.encoder 


out = pipe(["hello world", "foo bar", "this is a foo bar sentence"])

print(out[0].shape, out[1].shape, out[2].shape)
```

[out]:

```
torch.Size([1, 768]) torch.Size([1, 768]) torch.Size([1, 768])
```

#### Then, when didn't my method work but the pipeline does?

It's because when you have a batch, there's an attention mask that's being computed when sentences that are shorter than the max length of the batch is padded to the max. So when you try to extract the last hidden state, you'll have to account for the attention mask.

When you use `pipeline` it standardizes the batch size you put into the dataset. And usually it's set to 1.

#### But I really want to do batch_size larger than 1!

First, see:

- [How to compute mean/max of HuggingFace Transformers BERT token embeddings with attention mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083581/how-to-compute-mean-max-of-huggingface-transformers-bert-token-embeddings-with-a)
- https://www.philschmid.de/custom-inference-huggingface-sagemaker

Then you'll have to take in the attention mask when computing the max-pooling.

```
from transformers import MT5EncoderModel, AutoTokenizer

model = MT5EncoderModel.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")

texts = ["hello world", "foo bar", "this is a foo bar sentence"]

encoded_input = tokenizer(texts, padding=True, return_tensors='pt')
model_output = model(input_ids=encoded_input.input_ids)
attention_mask = encoded_input['attention_mask']


def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)


def max_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state
    input_mask_expanded = torch.where(attention_mask==0, -1e-9, 0.).unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.max(token_embeddings-input_mask_expanded, 1).values


mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask).shape, max_pooling(model_output, attention_mask).shape
```

[out]:

```
(torch.Size([3, 768]), torch.Size([3, 768]))
```

***Q: But are the value of the pooled embeddings with different batch the same?***

A:

```
from transformers import MT5EncoderModel, AutoTokenizer

model = MT5EncoderModel.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-base")

texts = ["hello world", "foo bar", "this is a foo bar sentence"]

encoded_input = tokenizer(texts, padding=True, return_tensors='pt')
model_output = model(input_ids=encoded_input.input_ids)
attention_mask = encoded_input['attention_mask']


def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)


def max_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output.last_hidden_state
    input_mask_expanded = torch.where(attention_mask==0, -1e-9, 0.).unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.max(token_embeddings-input_mask_expanded, 1).values


x = max_pooling(model_output, attention_mask)

text = ["hello world", "foo bar"]

encoded_input = tokenizer(texts, padding=True, return_tensors='pt')
model_output = model(input_ids=encoded_input.input_ids)
attention_mask = encoded_input['attention_mask']

y = max_pooling(model_output, attention_mask)

# Lets check all values in the "embeddings" of "hello World" in both batch sizes.
assert all(v for v in x[0] == y[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the model to evaluation mode by calling `model.eval()`. Normally model is set to train mode when it's initialized in which the dropout (randomly) and normalization is activate, we need to deactivate it in evaluation mode.

Comment: I tried this. Still getting the same results